# How to know if the "iris" start animation of a UIImagePickerController is over?

Tags: animation, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a tabbed app, that in one of thos tabs will show a UIImagePickerController to get a picture from the camera. I use a overlay view, but when the camera take almost 3 seconds to "open" the "irs" (starting animation), my overlay view is already visible, over the closed iris!!!

I need to check how to test if the iris is still close, so I can hidde the overlay view.

I read some posts about subclassing the UIImagePickerController, but apple said that we should not do that wifh UIImagePickerController.

Any one has a clue?

Answer (score 0):

The iris animation fires on the `[UIImagePickerController viewDidAppear]` method.  Apple discourages subclassing UIImagePickerController for a variety of reasons, but if you need to add you overlay after the iris animation finishes and are not willing to write your own Image Capture class with AVFoundation, i would do something like this:

If you don't already have one, add a new subclass of `UITabBarViewController` with a UIImagePickerController `@property` and delegates for `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and  `UINavigationControllerDelegate`

```
@interface my_TabBarViewController : UITabBarController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImagePickerController *picker;
```

In the implementation, add an `initCamera` method and call it in your `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)initCamera
{

  _picker                     = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  _picker.sourceType          = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
  _picker.view.frame          = CGRectMake(0.f, 20.f, 320.f, 499.f);
  _picker.navigationBarHidden = TRUE;
  _picker.delegate            = self;
  _picker.cameraOverlayView   = YourCameraOverlayView;
  [self.view addSubview:_picker.view];
  [_picker viewDidAppear:FALSE];

  [self.view sendSubviewToBack:_picker.view];

}
```

Then when your camera view tab bar item is tapped, show the camera with a method like this on your tab bar controller:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
  NSLog(@"tapped: %@", item.title);

  if ([item.title isEqualToString:@"Camera"]) {
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_picker.view];
  } else {
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:_picker.view];
  }
}
```

Finally, in your `UIImagePickerController` delegate method on the Tab Bar controller, clean up the Image Picker, and send the info dictionary to your Camera View controller to handle the image however you need to:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  [_picker.view removeFromSuperview];

  yourCameraViewController *camVC = (yourCameraViewController*)[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
  // Index 1 would just be the second tab, adjust accordingly
  [camVC imagePickerController:picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:info];

  [self initCamera];
}
```

The call to `[self initCamera];` here would re-initialize the `UIImagePickerController` which you may or may not want to do here. I would likely just `#import "my_TabBarViewController.h` in your `yourCameraViewController` and then you could grab the pointer to `picker` in your `UIImagePickerController` delegate method by calling:

```
my_TabBarViewController *tabBarVC = (my_TabBarViewController*)self.tabBarController;
```

and have `yourCameraViewController` dismiss it and message `tabBarVC` to re-init the `UIImagePickerController` when you need it again.